# Javascript, Jquery - can't change content of div on phone, works on desktop

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, dom

I can't change content of div  when using mobile view, it works perfectly fine when using desktop view. The output in console is correct, but its not shown in div.

Example of code:

```
<div id="dateandtime" class=""></div>
<div id="dateandtime2" class=""></div>
<div id="dateandtime3" class=""></div>
<script>
    jQuery(document).ready(function() {
        let datea = "${dogodek.eventDate}".split(" ")[0];
        let timea = "${dogodek.eventDate}".split(" ")[1];
        let timeArray = timea.split(":");
        timea = timeArray[0] + ":" + timeArray[1];
        console.log('date: ', datea, ', time: ', timea);
        $('#dateandtime2').html(datea);
        $('#dateandtime3').text(datea);
        $('#dateandtime').append(datea);
        console.log("done");
        document.getElementById('dateandtime').innerHTML += 'Extra stuff';
    });
    document.getElementById('dateandtime').innerHTML += 'Extra stuff';
</script>
```

Comment: First I would put some static text into the div to check if it's visible on phone. For example: `<div id="dateandtime" class="">hello</div>`

Comment: @kol static content is visible

Comment: Which phone and which mobile browser version do you use to test your code?

Comment: @kol i am testing it dev tools, chrome browser

Comment: It works for me in Chrome 94, mobile view (I only kept and set the datea variable, and had to delete timea and timeArray).

Comment: By the way, `"${dogodek.eventDate}"` looks like a template literal, but then it should have backticks instead of quotes: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals

Comment: looks like i have a problem somewhere else in the project then, it still doesn't work for me